# How to program this GUI in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I'm currently developing a small utility with the following GUI:

[image: Sample GUI]

Right now i have a container (JPanel) with the BorderLayout layout that holds everything in place. The i have another 2 JPanels placed on BorderLayout.NORTH and BorderLayout.SOUTH respectively, each whith the GridLayout (2 columns by 1 row). The table is on the main container placed at the CENTER of it.

Do you think this is the best approach? I'm having a rough time dealing with spacing between the components and the borders of the frame.

Right now i have this code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JButton loadFileBtn = new JButton("Load File");
    private JButton generateReportBtn = new JButton("Generate Report");
    private JButton exitBtn = new JButton("Exit");
    private JLabel fileNameLbl = new JLabel("File Name Here");
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu fileMI = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenuItem openFileMenu = new JMenuItem("Open File");
    private JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
    private JMenuItem exitMenu = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    private JMenu reportMI = new JMenu("Report");
    private JMenuItem generateReportMenu = new JMenuItem("Generate Report");
    private JMenu helpMI = new JMenu("Help");
    private JMenuItem aboutMenu = new JMenuItem("About");
    private JTable table = new JTable(5, 2);
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
    private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    private JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));

    public GUI() {

        super("Sample GUI");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setResizable(false);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));

        fileMI.add(openFileMenu);
        fileMI.add(separator);
        fileMI.add(exitMenu);

        reportMI.add(generateReportMenu);

        helpMI.add(aboutMenu);

        menuBar.add(fileMI);
        menuBar.add(reportMI);
        menuBar.add(helpMI);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        panel1.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panel2.add(fileNameLbl);
        panel2.add(loadFileBtn);

        panel3.add(generateReportBtn);
        panel3.add(exitBtn);

        mainPanel.add(panel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        add(mainPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GUI app = new GUI();
                app.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What do you think would be the best approach to do this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Right now, i have the following GUI

[image]

I want the components to space away from the borders evenly, like in the mockup.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Which space would you like to introduce and causes issues? You can always use `BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(int, int, int, int)`

Comment: @Guillaume Polet not sure, please not attack, are you meaning, to use `EmptyBorder` to avoiding `setPreferredSize`, or to use `EmptyBorder` to avoiding `SpringLayout` with `GridBagLayout` in the `NestedLayout` form , `MigLayout` or ...

Comment: @mKorbel Empty borders are a very easy (and sometime elegant) solution to properly position components in their container without having to switch to another LayoutManager. If the OP feels comfortable with those LayoutManager's, empty borders may be a good solution to his actual problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 things you can use to make this happen:

1. Use `BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(int, int, int, int)`
2. Use the 4-args constructor of `GridLayout`

There are other LayoutManager's which can bring the same functionality (like `GridBagLayout`, or using nested `BorderLayout`), but if you feel comfortable with the current `LayoutManager`'s, there is no imperious need to change to those. The way you did is also acceptable.

[image]

You might consider wrapping the table in a `JScrollPane` to make it nicer, with headers and scrollbars if ever needed.

Small example code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JButton loadFileBtn = new JButton("Load File");
    private JButton generateReportBtn = new JButton("Generate Report");
    private JButton exitBtn = new JButton("Exit");
    private JLabel fileNameLbl = new JLabel("File Name Here");
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu fileMI = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenuItem openFileMenu = new JMenuItem("Open File");
    private JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
    private JMenuItem exitMenu = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    private JMenu reportMI = new JMenu("Report");
    private JMenuItem generateReportMenu = new JMenuItem("Generate Report");
    private JMenu helpMI = new JMenu("Help");
    private JMenuItem aboutMenu = new JMenuItem("About");
    private JTable table = new JTable(5, 2);
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
    private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 10));
    private JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 10));

    public GUI() {

        super("Sample GUI");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setResizable(false);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));

        fileMI.add(openFileMenu);
        fileMI.add(separator);
        fileMI.add(exitMenu);

        reportMI.add(generateReportMenu);

        helpMI.add(aboutMenu);

        menuBar.add(fileMI);
        menuBar.add(reportMI);
        menuBar.add(helpMI);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        panel1.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panel2.add(fileNameLbl);
        panel2.add(loadFileBtn);

        panel3.add(generateReportBtn);
        panel3.add(exitBtn);

        mainPanel.add(panel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        add(mainPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GUI app = new GUI();
                app.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted. Thank you @Guillaume Polet.
I also tried GridBagLayout but i can't seem to grasp the concept. Any good tutorias you'd recommend? Tha one's on orcles's webpage are not that easy for a beginner.

Comment: hmmmm are you know that Empty JPanels added to W, E, S, N area to JFrame to create this gap automatically, there no reason to add EmptyBorders for this idea :-)

Comment: @mKorbel Do you suggest to rather add empty `JPanel` with a forced preferred size to the West, East, North and South of the JFrame?

Comment: Like @Gilbert Le Blanc suggested, using FlowLayout instead of GridLayout should be much more flexible and allow me to create the gap between the label and the button, on the north, and the two buttons, on the South area. What's your opinion?

Comment: @PMMP Depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you like to have buttons "equally" sized, `GridLayout` is the way to go. If now you prefer that each button has its own size and be aligned in some way, `FlowLayout` or `BoxLayout` are better candidates. There is no right or wrong `LayoutManager`'s, only appropriate ones for given needs/wishes.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet this gap is automatically created in Top-Level Container, BorderLayout, empty JPanel, no required any size, done by BorderLayout

Comment: @mKorbel OK I see what you mean now. If I add empty JPanels, the hGap and vGap of the BorderLayout will enter in action and will make an empty border appear automatically. Personnally, I still prefer the explicit empty border which has been created precisely to achieve the described effect. _Colors and tastes can always be argued...._ ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would arrange your GUI.  This is just one way.  It's not the only way.

- The `JTable` goes inside of a `JScrollPane`.
- `Button2` and `Button3` go inside of a button `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout`.
- `Label` and `Button1` go inside of a label `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout`.
- File, Report, and Help are `JMenuItem`s on a `JMenuBar`.
- The main `JPanel` has a `BoxLayout` with a Y_AXIS orientation.
- Add the label `JPanel`, the `JScrollPane`, and the button `JPanel` to the main `JPanel`.

Comment: Will try @Gilbert Le Blanc. Thanks for your input. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to create a GUI is to code in a way you and others will understand . Take a look at this [Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You can use different layout managers for different components. This will help you setting correct spacing.

If your problem is just the spacing around the components, set its [Insets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Insets.html).

Comment: Which Layout Managers do you recommend for this design? That is the motivation behind my question.

Comment: GridBagLayout is the most flexible in my opinion. But maybe I would mix some layout managers. Put a panel on top and in the bottom and table in the middle with BorderLayout. The panels in the bottom I would use FlowLayout and the panel int top maybe FlowLayout or GridBagLayout. Or do everything with GridBagLayout (a lot lot of coding).